# Textbox enabled or disabled based on radio button

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying following javascript to enable or disable textboxes based on radio buttons. but it does not seem to work.I am getting error like
 JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'checked' of undefined or null reference

```
 (function () {
        if (document.getElementById("<%=radioStartBusiness.ClientID%>").checked) {
            document.getElementById("<%=TextBoxReportPostingStartDate.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("<%=TextBoxReportBusinessStart.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
        }

        if (document.getElementById("<%=radioStartPosting.ClientID%>").checked) {
            document.getElementById("<%=TextBoxReportPostingStartDate.ClientID%>").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("<%=TextBoxReportBusinessStart.ClientID%>").disabled = true;
        }
    })();
```

and one of element in aspx page

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="radioStartBusiness" text="Start Business Date" AutoPostBack="true"
                                        runat="server" Checked="true" GroupName="StartOrPost" />
```

Comment: in which row of your code do you get this error? Sounds like the element with the given ID does not exist in the DOM ...

Comment: document.getElementById("<%=radioStartBusiness.ClientID%>").checked . i checked element .it's there

Comment: try this: var elem = document.getElementById("<%=radioStartBusiness.ClientID%>"); Then output elem with "alert(elem)" or console.log(elem) to check if element was found

Comment: You are right. it's not finding my element.var elem is giving me null. i do not know why it's not finding. radio button element is right there in the same page

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means that getElementById didn't find a matching element. Try to check in the source code of the loaded page and not your file that you have on the server, if you actually have an element with an ID that matches your ASP variable.

Comment: i see element in source code. it is also converting into ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioStartBusiness in run time

Comment: Does your output javascript also contain "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_radioStartBusiness"? Because if it does some really strange things are going on